# How to use 'view.kwargs' correctly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a Profile Image for a user in a page  next to his username which is working fine and I have tried to use the same logic to add the profile image but it didn't work and I don't know what is the reason, there is no error message showing it is simply not showing because probably it is not written correctly.

I am trying to understand how to use the query function correctly so this is a trial for me

Here is the views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "user_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'),
profile=self.kwargs.get('profile'))           <---------------------------- Here is my trial to add profile
        return Post.objects.filter(designer=user, admin_approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Here is the template

```
            {{ view.kwargs.username }}               <---------------------- Showing correctly 
            <embed class="profile_image" src={{ view.kwargs.user.profile.image.url }}> <------------- not appearing
```

Comment: Are you getting a 404 in you image in developer tools and if so when you click on the image is it the right path?

Comment: how does your URL to the `UserPostListView` view look like?

Comment: Have you solved this? A_k?